# Coverting point cloud data (.ply) into a range image

Tags: python, image, range, point-clouds

I have a point cloud with XYZ data, I have read the .ply file using pyntcloud and converted it into a numpy array (553181,3)

I want to convert the point cloud e.g. into an 800x600x3 matrix that can be also treated as an RGB-image. For this, I scaled the XY-coordinates to [0,800] and [0,600] ranges.

so far ->

1. I have normalized the x and y coordinate to the range of (0,800) and (0,600)
2. I have created databins of size 800 and 600 and stored the respective x and y coordinate points
3. I don't know how to map these points to get a range image

I am new to python and would greatly appreciate the help and guidance

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand how you could possibly treat a 3d point cloud in a 2d image. Any way you could use [open3d](http://www.open3d.org/docs/latest/index.html) to visualize your point cloud and store it in .xyzrgb file if you have RGB data, which seems you don't since you converted the file into a NumPy array with 3 columns that have to be x, y and z values. Therefore, you may need RGB values or give random values to the point cloud. A good way to do that is using [pptk](https://heremaps.github.io/pptk/index.html), which allows you to generate RGB colors on a point cloud and to render images (screenshots) on a built-in viewer (I assume that is what you need).

A simple workflow could be this:

```
import pptk 
xyz = pptk.rand(100, 3) #generates a 3dimensions array or it could be a 
                        #numpy array - your (553181,3) array
v = pptk.viewer(xyz)
rgb = pptk.rand(100, 3) #same here, must be same size as what you used

#or you can create a single random color of the shape you need
import random
r = np.full(shape=100, fill_value=random.randint(1,255))
g = np.full(shape=100, fill_value=random.randint(1,255))
b = np.full(shape=100, fill_value=random.randint(1,255))
rgb = np.dstack((r,g,b))
colors = rgb/256  #you are going to need to convert the values in 
                  #0-1 interval

v.attributes(colors)
v.capture('screenshot.png')
```

Perhaps you would like to take a read to this [massive-3d-point-clouds-visualization-in-python](https://towardsdatascience.com/guide-to-real-time-visualisation-of-massive-3d-point-clouds-in-python-ea6f00241ee0). It describes more or less what I put in the example I made, which is just a "short form" of that.